# Optimizing datetime.date to unix timestamp conversion in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, optimization, unix-timestamp

I have been trying to do this as fast as possible, while also avoiding timezone problems.

This method seems to be the slowest:

```
def to_unix_timestamp(stamp):
    return int(stamp.strftime('%s'))
```

It yields the following results:

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
4328301    1.620    0.000   10.009    0.000 utils.py:13(to_unix_timestamp)
```

This seems to be a bit better, but still relatively slow for my liking:

```
def to_unix_timestamp(stamp):
    return time.mktime(stamp.timetuple())
```

Results:

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
4328301    1.381    0.000    8.158    0.000 utils.py:13(to_unix_timestamp)
```

Is there any way that I could achieve a major speedup without screwing with the timezones? Please note that I am limited to python 2.7.

Comment: Are these execution speeds limiting you somehow? Don't prematurely optimize

Comment: The project is basically done and this is the largest performance bottleneck. I would like to bring it down significantly to improve the user experience.

Comment: Define `d0 = datetime.date(1970, 1, 1)`, and then do `(stamp - d0).total_seconds()`?  I haven't actually timed this, and have no idea what timezone issues you're seeking to avoid.

Comment: Bravo - your idea brought it down to 1 second. However, I ran into the "timezone" issues I feared. Upon verification against the other methods, i found the time coming from this method to be offset by one hour forwards. Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: daylight savings?

Comment: @user129186 - How do you produce `stamp`?

Answer (score 0):

> > Define `d0 = datetime.date(1970, 1, 1)`, and then do `(stamp - d0).total_seconds()`? …
> >                         – jasonharper
>
> I ran into the "timezone" issues I feared. Upon verification against the other methods, i found the time coming from this method to be offset by one hour forwards. Any idea what might be causing this?

Yes, *the other methods* are implicitly using local time, accounting for your time zone. A `datetime.date` object `d0` (with 1-day resolution) doesn't carry that time zone information, hence the discrepancy when taking the difference `stamp - d0`. To rectify this, we can construct a `d0` which represents the true epoch:

```
d0 = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(0)
```

With that, `(datetime.datetime.combine(stamp, datetime.time.min) - d0).total_seconds()` yields the values you expect.